# How can I use ConnectApi.ModerationCapability to automatically flag records containing bad words?

Tags: apex, community, chatter, chatter-feed, connect-api

We have a requirement wherein chats/discussion(this is a custom object) having a bad words needs to be flagged in moderation to review.

How can I use ConnectApi.ModerationCapability to automatically flagged chats/discussions?

After finding some ways on how to use this, I can't find any article relation to this. Anyone here have an idea on how to us ConnectApi.ModerationCapability?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say this but the Moderation feature is only available in a Community and only on Feed Element, comment and file. Moderation does not support custom objects.

More information on Community Moderation

[Moderation Overview](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_moderation_overview.htm&type=5)
[Moderation APEX API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_ConnectAPI_CommunityModeration_static_methods.htm#apex_ConnectAPI_CommunityModeration_static_methods)
[Moderation Connect API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resources_communities_moderation.htm)